# Random Http error while using Youtube api to get comments through python

Tags: python, http-error, youtube-data-api

on a random basis getting random Http errors while trying to get comments from predefined videos with YouTube API v3 on python. The case: giving list of video ids and comments are downloaded for each one until python throws error, and process stops. If i reload program it might stuck on the same or on another video and on different comments as well. Errors ranging from 40* till 500 as well on random basis.
Tried to put code in try except, didn't help. Anything else i can do except remembering last scrapped video id and reloading manually program?
The code:

```
import httplib2
import urllib2
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

from apiclient.discovery import build_from_document
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
DEVELOPER_KEY = "---"
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SSL_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

listL = list()
listL.append("D0uEXoL04OM")
listL.append("eX8-g9wM_Sc")
listL.append("aKInxyP5l7k")
listL.append("vMp__taMQtE")
listL.append("Zd3qcqGKbYA")
listL.append("69sg2o2phVs")
listL.append("QcGhVY3ieu4")
listL.append("t4QhJOFo2S0")
listL.append("NeJPr6ko2Hk")
listL.append("15ka3dFn6LI")
listL.append("hweA36OyxRM")
listL.append("ZmCv5HJJPqQ")
listL.append("zfi5DamYZxA")
listL.append("x7O3GVAqCio")
listL.append("kAbhm5NJTz8")
listL.append("7URzyREVdao")



def comment_threads_list_by_video_id(service, part, video_id):
    res = service.commentThreads().list(
    part=part,
    videoId=video_id,
    maxResults="100",
  ).execute()

    nextPageToken = res.get('nextPageToken')
    while ('nextPageToken' in res):
        nextPage = service.commentThreads().list(
        part="snippet",
        videoId=video_id,
        maxResults="100",
        pageToken=nextPageToken
        ).execute()
        res['items'] = res['items'] + nextPage['items']
        if 'nextPageToken' not in nextPage:
            res.pop('nextPageToken', None)
        else:
            nextPageToken = nextPage['nextPageToken']

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
for item in listL: 
        try:
            print item
            comment_threads_list_by_video_id(youtube, 'snippet, replies', item)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
            print "Http Error happened"
            pass
        except urllib2.URLError, err:
            print "Some other error happened:", err.reason
            pass
```

EDIT: --------------------------
Few errors

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?pageToken=ChYQpqWd6pfYzgIYyISxrpfYzgIgACgcEhQIABDIhLGul9jOAhiQgZuP9IfOAhgCIO4VKJHr35vwuKix-gE%3D&part=snippet&key=AIzaSyBzExhLoWbeHU1iKHZuaYV7IBPJNiyaDkE&alt=json&videoId=D0uEXoL04OM&maxResults=100 returned "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.">
```

Comment: please also post few samples of errors you get with relevant error texts.

Comment: Is it possible you are simply reaching the limit of requests per second of the v3 api?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, now i'm only getting 'http 400 error' on a random basis, which i didn't get before, maybe tomorrow during the day some different will appear.

Comment: @Av4t4r, thanks its interesting proposition, but how to check or avoid that?

Comment: @Darius check out this utility https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost to check for cost. To be honest, I'm not sure how to avoid getting to that limit. Perhaps add a simple sleep or wait method once you reached a certain ammount of requests?

Comment: @Av4t4r, thanks for the link and suggestion. I'll try that some to put  time.sleep, maybe it will solve problems

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake was made. Instead of API used error identifier in 'exception'

```
...
except HttpError, err:
...
```

Urlib2 one was used

```
...
except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
...
```

The simple solution was just to ignore and repeat until success. However, still not clear why these random errors are coming. Sleep didn't help.